# Keypad not fully displayed for "time" inputType

Tags: android, time, android-edittext, keypad

I was trying to configure an EditText to display a "time" keypad when a user edits GPS coordinates.  The keypad doesn't appear to fit inside the display window, it gets cut off.  This doesn't appear to happen with other keypad (InputType) layouts.  Does anyone have an idea why this can be happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LatitudeDegrees"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:digits="0123456789.:"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/EnterDegreesHintString"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FDFD67"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've simplified the layout from what I started with, but it reproduces the issue just as well.

Note that the manifest defines the activity with the following theme attribute: android:theme="@style/FloatingWindow"

```
<style name="FloatingWindow" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And the layout padding uses the following definitions:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

[image: EditText for latitide in floating window using time keypad]

Comment: have you tried on other devices?

Comment: Yes, the Samsung and LG devices that I have, from Android 4.4 through 9 seem to be affected.  I don't have a device with version 10.

Comment: please post your full xml layout

Comment: Hai, please see the modified layout and extra details above

Comment: I need the theme style also

Comment: Yes, of course.  Again, please see the extra details above

Comment: Please note, Hai, that the same thing happens if I don't define theme in the manifest for this activity.  Theme doesn't seem to be a part of the problem.